# How to avoid unclosed regions in vim syntax highlight?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have custom vim syntax highlighting for files that look like:

```
--- Start foo

++ Block
...
--

++ Another block
--

--- Stop foo

--- Start bar

++ Unclosed block
--- Stop bar

Something outside
```

Everything between `--- Start` and `--- Stop` is a foldable region, and everything between `++` and `--` is another foldable region. The problem is that the last region (`++ Unclosed block`) has no closing line, so everything down to the end of the file is recognized (and folded) within this region, with the result that `Something outside`, which should be outside any region and fold, is enclosed in a second-level fold instead.

Can I define the regions to require an end match before the end of the file?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html):

> Note: The decision to start a region is only based on a matching start
>   pattern.  There is no check for a matching end pattern.

So one possibility is turning the region into a match:

```
syntax match InnerBlock "^++ \_.\{-}\n--$" fold contains=InnerBlock
```

but this makes it much slower. Another option is making the InnerBlock stop at `--- Stop` too, so at least the `Something outside` line stays outside folds. Note `keepend` must be added to the OuterBlock definition:

```
syntax region OuterBlock
      \ start="^--- Start .*$"
      \ end="^--- Stop .*$"
      \ fold
      \ contains=InnerBlock
      \ keepend

syn region InnerBlock
      \ start="^++ .*$"
      \ end="^--$"
      \ end="^--- Stop .*$"
      \ fold
      \ contains=InnerBlock
```